# How to keep source ip address when redirecting TCP traffic

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, boost-asio, portforwarding

I made a linux application that modifies traffic which comes to specified port and redirecting that traffic to another port ( local application ) using `boost::asio`. When my app accepts new tcp connection it creates new connection with target port and receive all data from source and target and pass to each other ( + modify traffic ), my app is in middle between internet and target application. All seems to be ok except one thing, when target process accepts new connection ( connection from my app ) it sees that source ip is `127.0.0.1` ( + using `getpeername` ), how can i make new connection that way so target app will see source ip as original source ip of connection from internet as on image below:

[image: Maybe using RAW sockets?]

Maybe using RAW sockets? Is it possible to create own TCP handshake process with spoofed source ip address and then pass file descriptor to `boost::asio` instead of using `boost::async_connect`? But will outgoing traffic from target process go directly to internet avoiding my filtering app?

Unfortunately, i can't inject to target process using `LD_PRELOAD` as it was compilled statically. Also i'm unable to use my own kernel module

Comment: To be able to use a new TCP connection, you must use the actual address of the host trying to create the connection, which is your own process because a TCP connection is bidirectional (a connection of peers). What you seem to be trying to do is NAT (Network Address Translation) that replaces an address in the packet, but that creates a problem because you then need to fix the IP and TCP headers. Remember that with TCP, the TCP on the two hosts (peers, not client/server for TCP) must create an end-to-end connection that negotiates parameters.

Comment: Not sure what type of traffic your dealing with but if it's HTTP you can use the X-Forwarded-For proto